# JavaScript: Express POST request... getting rate-limited or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, express, rate-limiting

I am trying to post data from my react frontend to my express backend. The first 5 or so requests go through, then it seems to just stop. I have a console log in the backend that logs when a post goes through and it literally just stops working after that. Am I running into some rate-limit or what?

Comment: Can you add the code for the route handler?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We can't begin to help you without more context (is this local? on a service? what servie?) and probably a [mcve] of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am so dumb. I just wasn't returning a status code and after checking the network tab it was pending. res.sendStatus(200) worked :P